# Subtracting a fixed value from cv::Mat objects in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, matrix

I am fairly new to OpenCV and sort of understanding it bit by bit. I know that the matrix operators in `cv::Mat` class has been overloaded to do A.mult(B), A+B, A-B, A/B, etc.

I have two vectors which are projections of rows and columns of an image. I have two images(S and T), so each of them will have two projection vectors (rowProejctionS, columnProjectionS, rowProjectionT, columnProjectionT). I also have the means of the images (meanS, meanT). I need to do a "SUM OF PRODUCT" related calculation, which in MATLAB is as follows

```
numeratorLambdaRo = sum((rowProjectionT - meanT).*(rowProjectionS - meanS));
denominatorLambdaRo = sqrt(sum((rowProjectionT - meanT).^2)*sum((rowProjectionS - meanS).^2);

LambaRo = numeratorLambdaRo/denominatorLambdaRo;
```

I am not entirely sure about the capability of matrix operators in the context of `cv::Mat` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare meanT, meanS as double or cv::Scalar and you can just substract it from your matrix. You can maybe split your operations :

```
rowProjectionT -= meanT;
rowProjectionS -= meanS;
numeratoLambdaRo = cv::sum(rowProjectionT*rowProjectionS.t()); // transpose 1 of the vector so that multiplication is equivalent to dot product.

cv::Mat rowProjTSquare = rowProjectionT*rowProjectionT.t();
cv::Mat rowProjSSquare = rowProjectionS*rowProjectionS.t();
denominatorLambdaRo = sqrt(cv::sum(rowProjTSquare*rowProjSSquare));
```

Comment: @Remi..Thanks for the solution! I tried to play another game with my MMU (by using cv::isContinuous() function)....If I am lucky, then the memory assignment should be continuous and therefore the data can be extracted by Mat::data pointer. Hopefully It is another solution. BUT +1 to you because your solution doesn't involve pointers and I personally hate pointers (because I am a java developer by skills :P) hi hi...

Comment: @Remi...Your matrix multiplication with * sign doesn't work! Does it requires some header file to suggest operator overloading?

Comment: Check the matrix dimensions. It might be rowProjTSquare = rowProjT.t()*rowProjectionT. In one case you end up with a scalar (1x1 matrix), on the other case, a (dxd) matrix where d is the dimension of your vector.

Comment: You should take advantage of the higher level matrix functionalities instead of messing with raw data, unless you are a really good programmer. Those operations should be implemented pretty neatly in the library

Comment: Hi..I checked both matrices are they are simply empty :( Is there any other way? I did this:
`rowProjTSquare.c.row(0) // Gives error
`rowProjTSquare.c.s.val[0] // doesn't give anything'

Any thoughts :(?  SOrry but I have been trying for long, (don't know  how hard is hard enough)