# Matrix Multiplication using cv::Mat

Tags: opencv

I have previously asked [a question about matrix multiplication in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13119414/209139) and managed to find the correct answer. However, when I try to do this, I get erroneous results:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {

// Vars.
int a[4] = {3,2,1,4};
int b[4] = {2,5,6,1};

// Pointers
int *p1, *p2;
int res(5);

// Init.
p1 = &a[0];
p2 = &b[0];

for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    res += (*(p1+i) - 2)*(*(p2+i) - 3);
}
cout << res << endl; // This is fine!

unsigned int p[4] = {3,1,2,4};
cv::Mat testMat = cv::Mat(1,4,CV_8U,p);
cout << testMat << endl; // Shows [3, 0, 0, 0] !!!!!
cout << testMat.at<unsigned int>(0,3) << endl; // Displays 4


//cv::Mat resDot = testMat*(testMat.t());
cv::Mat testMatTransp(testMat.t());
cout << testMatTransp.at<unsigned int>(0,0) << endl; // Shows Jibrish 56928323
return(0);
}
```

Unless I am missing something, this could should print out all the information correctly, right? Am I supposed to call any destructor or anything? I thought it is based on RAII, so unless I use "new" based initialisation, I don't need to call destructors. Is that right? Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in

```
cv::Mat testMat = cv::Mat(1,4,CV_8U,p);
```

CV_8U means 8 bit unsigned.  If you change it to

```
cv::Mat testMat = cv::Mat(1,4,CV_32S,p);
```

it should work.  Alternatively, changing

```
unsigned int p[4] = {3,1,2,4};
```

to

```
unsigned char p[4] = {3,1,2,4};
```

should work too

Comment: CV_32S is a 32-bit integer with Single Channel, is it correct? I am interested in unsigned int type. Basically, when I tried my algorithm out in MATLAB, I was playing around with uint8 and therefore, I needed to keep it the same. But +1 for the solution :)!! –

Comment: @jjabraham Why do you need it to be an unsigned int?  You can keep uint8, just change your input to uchar...

Comment: Hey man! Thanks for the answer...It works like a magic when I changed from CV_8U to CV_32S, unfortunately it doesn't work if unsigned char p is declared instead of unsigned int p. I think there is a precision-related bug in openCV or something has not been clarified properly in the documentation. However, +1 to you as you have solved it with a trivial change!! :)

Comment: @jjabraham glad it works.  That is strange, I tested it and I get correct output with unsigned char p.  Ghost in the machine I guess...

Comment: @hammer...are you using 2.4.3?....it seems to be really unstable and problem-prone

Comment: @jjabraham if you can narrow down exactly what the problem is, you should submit a bug report.  2.4.3 isn't actually out yet, what you have is 2.4.3 release candidate, they are trying to fix all its bugs before releasing 2.4.3 see [http://opencv.org/](http://opencv.org/)

Comment: FINALLY!!!! Got somebody who suggested it could be a BUG!! Reported already under bug section....:) It is genuinely a bug!!